# execute external php file using exec()

Tags: php

i am new to exec function and need help with executing an external php file. My code of the files are as follows

Script.php(main file) :

```
<?php 
$path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/user/execute.php';
exec($path, $output,$return);
var_dump($return);
echo "hi"."<br>";
echo "end";?>
```

execute.php(calling file) :

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
echo "hello"."<br>";
}
```

trying to execute the calling file

Comment: Why do you need `exec()` just include the file?!

Comment: But... why do you want to run it with exec()? I can't think of a reason to ever do this.

Comment: `exec('php ' . $path, $output, $return);` You may need to change `php` to the full path of the executable.

Comment: Take a look at output buffering http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Hello i want to run the exec function as i need to put a function in the background until i complete a particular action on my form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
exec("php execute.php > /dev/null &");
```

solved my problem..Thanks all

Comment: this is for linux systems, your question was on code for windows systems. You are a silly dev Rebecca. :P ;)

Comment: @mondjunge: i used the same answer which was suggested by u but the only difference made is the exec statement as i need the other file to be executed in the background, for your code i had to wait for the other file to get executed.....

Answer (score 2):

`exec` is for executing system functions, not for running scripts. (Take a look at the manual, it's helping: http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php)

To achieve what you want, you could pass the path to php executable and add the script as parameter, like this:

```
<?php
$phpExecutable = 'C:/xampp/bin/php.exe' 
$path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/user/execute.php';
exec($phpExecutable." ".$path, $output,$return);
var_dump($return);
echo "hi"."<br>";
echo "end";?>
```

Should work. I do not know where your php executable is located, so please adapt it to your location.

Happy coding.

Comment: It may also be that you'd need to use 'C:/xampp/bin/php-cli.exe'

Comment: @mondjunge : i tried your code but still i see that after my other called file is executed it is executing the main file. i need to call the called file and put it to background and make the main file work till then.. please help

Comment: I never worked with subprocesses in PHP. This is possible, but you need to figure it out on your own or ask a new question. Here is the PHP function you possibly need to do what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php Also the Observer/Obserable Pattern should help, but I am not sure if this is possible in PHP.

Comment: Oh, yes, Observer/Obserable is possible with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splsubject.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as guys said in comments, you don't need `exec()` here at all. You can just `include` that file.

Anyway, `exec()` function executes **external program**. A `.php` file is **not** a program, it's just a script that is executed by a program called php.

So you can run it like:

```
exec('php ' . $path, $output,$return);
```

`php` also can require you to give full path to its executable if it's not available globally.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php